# Trouble to migrate some flavors from Firebase CrashReport to Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, android-productflavors

So we have an Android application which was monitored using **Firebase Crash Report** and we updated it a couple weeks ago to **migrate to Firebase Crashlytics**.

We followed the (pretty straightforward) [official procedure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-from-crash-reporting) and tested it on our development flavor. It took some time for the first test crash reports to pop up but it definitively worked.

But we tried it this week on **another flavor** of our application and it **does not work** in this case. Looking closer, we can see the following lines in Logcat :

```
com.ourapp.flavorb I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.6.3.25
com.ourapp.flavorb I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
com.ourapp.flavorb D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
    com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
com.ourapp.flavorb E/Fabric: Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/com.ourapp.flavorb/settings
com.ourapp.flavorb W/CrashlyticsCore: Received null settings, skipping report submission!
```

The working flavor has the following output :

```
com.laposte.tvfacteur.integration I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.6.3.25
com.ourapp.flavora I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
com.ourapp.flavora D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
    com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
com.ourapp.flavora I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: [SOME-UID]
```

Is there something we're missing ? It seems we did nothing more for the first flavor…

I'm under the impression that Firebase creates at some point a settings entry in Crashlytics servers and, for some reason, it has not worked for the second flavor.

Does anyone saw something like that ? Any idea on things we could try ?

Any help will be welcomed !

Comment: Mike from Firebase and Fabric. Thanks for sharing your solution, it's strange that this happened, but I'm glad you're all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So… It's kinda weird but it finally works for both flavors !

Seems that it took a looooooooooooooong time to process the new flavor. My guess is that some kind of account is automatically created on Crashlytics on first report. In my case, it took nearly a week !

I also uninstalled/reinstalled the application multiple times, maybe it helped…

Just for my archives, here is the situation before :
[image]

And after :
[image]